# Initializinf Sql*Plus error

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, sqlplus

when I make initiate following statement from terminal

```
sqlplus sys as sysdba
```

I am getting error

```
Error  initializing SQL*Plus
SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found.
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle Software directory.
```

I have already mentioned the ORACLE_HOME.

Comment: Have you done `export ORACLE_HOME`, to make it visible to new processes; or only set it in your current shell? You need to check `PATH`, `ORACLE_SID` and maybe `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are set and exported properly too.

Answer (score 0):

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0
export ORACLE_SID= DB_SID
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH:
```

now try to use sqlplus utility and share the results